# Site logo and logo link for external users

Tags: external-users, site-logo

We have enabled sharing on a classic publishing site ( for authorized users) and when they log on the logo is not visible. I figured out that external users do not have access to Site Assets which it where the logo is stored. So after adding the external users with read permissions the logo appeared, however the link is gone for externals, any idea how to reenable it?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you need a logo link if logo is already visible to external users?

Comment: The link I am refering to is the on the logo, the one that takes you to the default page of the site. That link is missing for external users

Comment: Is the default page published and visible to external users? Do the externals have access to library where default page lies?

Comment: That will be a yes to both. The external users can see the page and the logo, but the link had been stripped from the DOM

Comment: Stripped from DOM? You mean the page is out of shape i.e. looks weird??

Comment: Not at all, but this href has been stripped for the external users : <a class="ms-siteLogo-defaultLogo" href="https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/leaps-pro/testskole1" aria-label="Test skole 1"><div class="ms-siteLogo-actual"><img role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" src="/sites/leaps-pro/PublishingImages/testskole1 logo.png"></div></a>